# OpenCV build error C2065?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I seemed to get this OpenCV error C2065 'val' undeclared identifer out of nowhere with my opencv projects. It is an error in the opencv2\core\operations.hpp file which I have never touched. I have been using opencv for the past month with success and all the sudden this error popped out of nowhere when i just opened up my project to work on it.

I also tried re-downloading opencv and chose a different version of opencv and this same error pops up when I run the new opencv on a dummy program like the one below. I am very confused on what is happening.

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    cout << "test";

    return 0;
}
```

This is where the it says the error occurs in operations.hpp on lines with 'val'

```
template<> inline Vec<float, 3> Vec<float, 3>::cross(const Vec<float, 3>& v) const
{
    return Vec<float,3>(val[1]*v.val[2] - val[2]*v.val[1],
                     val[2]*v.val[0] - val[0]*v.val[2],
                     val[0]*v.val[1] - val[1]*v.val[0]);
}

template<> inline Vec<double, 3> Vec<double, 3>::cross(const Vec<double, 3>& v) const
{
    return Vec<double,3>(val[1]*v.val[2] - val[2]*v.val[1],
                     val[2]*v.val[0] - val[0]*v.val[2],
                     val[0]*v.val[1] - val[1]*v.val[0]);
}
```

Does anybody know why this could possibly be happening? I have no idea what is going on....any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please post the line in operations.hpp where the error occurs

Comment: The error occurs in lines 1456-1458 and 1463-1465.